# use of this in PHP

Tags: php, this

I am new to PHP and need your help here. I know the basic functionality of `this` in PHP.

```
class SwapClass
{
    public $num1 = 0;
    public $num2 = 0;
    function __construct($val1,$val2)
    {
        echo "In constructor!!" . "<br />";
        $num1 = $val1;
        $num2 = $val2;
    }
    public function display()
    {   
        echo "1st value : " . $num1 . "<br />2nd value : " . $num2;
    }
}
```

This is my class. I called it as:

```
$obj = new SwapClass(2,3);
$obj->display();
```

The values never come to the `display()` method. I tried echoing it in the constructor. It's confirmed that values are coming. I then modified the code to:

```
class SwapClass
{
    public $num1 = 0;
    public $num2 = 0;
    function __construct($val1,$val2)
    {
        echo "In constructor!!" . "<br />";
        $this->num1 = $val1;
        $this->num2 = $val2;
    }
    public function display()
    {   
        echo "1st value : " . $this->num1 . "<br />2nd value : " . $this->num2;
    }
}
```

It works fine now. Why does can't the variables be accessed without `this`?

Is `this` used for disambiguation? In my example I have just one object. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any member of class is recognized buy using `$this` in class.

Otherwise it will be treated as local variable where it is being used.

It does not depend on number of object of class, You need to use it for one object as well as for hundreds and more.

http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-the-keyword-this-in-php/

Comment: Copied from here http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-the-keyword-this-in-php/  you should mention the source from the code is copied in your answer And avoid to copy paste here on SO. You can be suspended. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: @whoami I have not copied code from whatever site you are saying. I'm a newbie to PHP that doesnt mean I'm new to OOPS concepts or programming languages. The above written code solely belongs to me. I prefer leaving stackoverflow than being charged with such accusations

Comment: @ruki : It was not for you. It was for me.

Comment: @ruki: That was not for you. Get help from here whenever you need